# react-native-modal working on debugging but not on release

Tags: reactjs, react-native, debugging, react-native-ios

I'm using [react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal) in react-native, it's works perfect while i am on debug, but the app freezes the moment i try to toggle it while the app is in release, I have no idea why's that and found no such issue in the dependency's repo, neither i found something here in stackoverflow

Here is my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "i18n-js": "^3.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "native-base": "^2.8.1",
    "react": "16.6.1",
    "react-native": "0.57.5",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-audio": "^4.2.2",
    "react-native-checkbox": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-dropdownalert": "^3.7.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.1.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.21.3",
    "react-native-languages": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.2.8",
    "react-native-opentok": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.10.9",
    "react-native-spinkit": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-stars": "^1.1.5",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.49.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.1"
  },
```

Here is my modal.js

```
import React from 'react';

import Modals from 'react-native-modal';

const Modal = props => (
    <Modals isVisible={ props.is_visible } onBackdropPress={ () => props.toggle_modal(false) }>
        { props.children }
    </Modals>
)

export default Modal;
```

And here is an example of how i am using it

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.toggle_modal('is_change_language_modal_visible') } style={ styles.settings_item_container }>

    <Text style={ styles.settings_item_label }> { i18n.t('change_language') } </Text>

</TouchableOpacity>

<Modal is_visible={ this.state.is_change_language_modal_visible } toggle_modal={ () => this.toggle_modal('is_change_language_modal_visible') }>

   <ChangeLanguage
     change_language={ this.change_language }
   />

</Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Debug App on Android-Device**

Did you got some output at your Device with *logcat*?

You could run logcat at an USB-Connected device, to get more feedback, why the app is quitting. Android-Studio can be used as nice gui for logcat, but there are also some other tools... at least use the adb logcat command.

**How to start Logcat in Android-Studio**

If you use android-studio, make sure to use your /android-Directory inside your Projectfolder as Project-Root (don't use your react-native-project-root !). Then open Logcat with pressing SHIFT thee times and typinng Logcat

**Debug App on IOS-Device**

For IOs, use: `xcrun instruments -s devices`

You even can open it this way with XCode:

1. Start Xcode
2. Windows -> Devices & Simulators
3. Choose your Device
4. Click on Button `Open Console`

Comment: How may i do that !?

Comment: Can i get debugging in release ?

Comment: If you use Android there is `adb`. You can install it at your PC to connect to your USB-Plugged device. Then you could run `adb logcat`.  You even could start androidStudio and open the Logcat in this GUI (it's a bit more compfortable).  With logcat, you see every message that appears at your real-device.

Comment: You have to add this information to your question! For IOs, use: `xcrun instruments -s devices`